# what is the syntax for writing anchor tag for location?

Tags: docusignapi

I am newbie to docusign api.

I have created a demo project using Anchor text tag. 
I am calling the CreateAndSendEnvelope method and settting the url in iframe.
Anchor Text tag is not getting replaced by Docusign control.
is there any specific syntax that need to used?

I have tried below syntax for textbox 1) tbx_1_text_tag 2)\tbx2_1_text.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've mentioned the `CreateAndSendEnvelope` function I'm assuming your using DocuSign's SOAP api instead of REST.  You should reference the SOAP SDK that's up on GitHub as that has lots of examples and working code in 4 different language stacks:

https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK

For instance, if you were using PHP this should work:

```
$fullAnchor = new Tab();
$fullAnchor->Type = TabTypeCode::FullName;
$anchor = new AnchorTab();
$anchor->AnchorTabString = "\tbx2_1_text";
$anchor->XOffset = -123;
$anchor->YOffset = 31;
$anchor->Unit = UnitTypeCode::Pixels;
$anchor->IgnoreIfNotPresent = true;
$fullAnchor->AnchorTabItem = $anchor;
$fullAnchor->DocumentID = "1";
$fullAnchor->PageNumber = "2";
$fullAnchor->RecipientID = "1";
array_push($tabs, $fullAnchor);
```

If you were using the DocuSign REST api you could do this:

```
"tabs": {
  "signHereTabs": [
    {
    "anchorString": "\tbx2_1_text",
    "anchorXOffset": "1",
    "anchorYOffset": "0",
    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
    "anchorUnits": "inches"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am  using C# soap API. One more thing how to make this field conditionally display if I have one radio button if it is checked then i want to show this textbox?

Comment: You'll want to use the `conditionalParentLabel` and `conditionalParentValue` properties on a given tab for conditional logic.  The `conditionalParentLabel` configures which tab controls visibility of the child tab, the `conditionalParentValue` controls what value enables/disables it.  If you're doing a radio button you want to check against value 'on'.  Search the API guides for "conditional" for more info...